# how shall I check that a Future is not null

Tags: scala

The following code returns a `Future`.

```
val findUserFuture: Future[Option[User]] = userRepo.findOne(userKeys)
```

Then I process the `Future`

```
findUserFuture.flatMap {....}
.recover{...}
```

I suppose that `recover` will be called if `flatMap` throws an `Exception`. But what if `findOne` returns `null`? Is there a `Scala` specific way to check that `findUserFuture` is not `null`? I can I suppose do `if(findUserFuture != null)` but I am wondering is `Scala` provides some different way to check `null`s

Comment: It's unclear which case you are expecting. `Future` contains a value of `null` or `Future` itself is `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `findOne()` might return `null` (really? seems doubtful) then one thing you could do is transform the `null` into an instance of the expected type...

```
val findUserFuture: Future[Option[User]] = Option(userRepo.findOne(userKeys))
                                            .getOrElse(Future(None))
```

...and then continue processing normally.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose you are calling `apply` of `Option` companion object (`apply[A](x: A): Option[A]`) which creates `Some(x)` if the argument is not null, and `None` if it is null. - https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option$.html

Comment: Use: `Future.successful(None)`—there is no need to evaluate None asynchronously.

Answer (score 9):

There is a difference between the result of the `Future` and the `Future` itself, and between `null` and `None`.

`null` is a hang-over from Java that is typically not used in Scala. The only way that the `Future` itself could be `null` is if `findOne` returned `null`, which is very unlikely. So testing the `Future` itself is not going to be useful.

The result of the future is `Option[User]` so the code inside the `flatMap` will be give a value that is either `Some(user)` or `None`. You can use the standard `Option` methods to test this value. Typically you would `match` on the value or call `map` to process the contents, if present. There are lots of stackoverflow answers that explain how to unpick an `Option` value safely.

Note that the `Option[User]` value could be `null` but, again, this is very unlikely and would be an error in the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `map` then `match` the result..

```
Example:

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val findUserFuture: Future[Option[User]] = userRepo.findOne(userKeys) 
findUserFuture.map { 
   case Some(v) => println(v) // Not Null...
   case None => println(None) // None or Empty result..
}

Hope it helps.
```

Comment: If `findOne()` returns a `null` then mapping over it will throw NPE.

Comment: If `null` then you can change `case None => ` with `case _ =>` to handle everything that is not match with the first one.

Comment: Not so. `null.map{...` will throw before any `case` is evaluated.

Comment: But basically it won't be `null` because return type is `Future[Option[User]]` so maybe you'll get either `Future(Some(User(....)))` or `Future(None)` :)

Comment: Try this: `val findUserFuture: Future[Option[User]] = null` That compiles. Now `map()` over it. It will also compile, but it won't run.

Comment: I see now i get your point but if that will happen it's kind of ugly, and you need to fix your `userRepo.findOne(userKeys) ` function. :)

Comment: findUserFuture match { case v: Future[Option[User]] => v case _ => Some(None) } map { 
   case Some(v) => println(v) // Not Null...
   case None => println(None) // None or Empty result..
}

Comment: I agree. Returning `null` is not good, but that is exactly what the OP asks about: "But what if `findOne` returns `null`?"

Comment: If that will happen then simple simple `match` or `if statement` is enough for that one.

Comment: And also in order your function won't response with `null` You can set `default value` on your function.

Comment: OK, so stop adding more comments and edit your answer so that it actually addresses the questions that the OP is actually asking.